# Android app random native crash in monkey test

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Our Android application encounters random native crash in monkey test. We have some jni and native C++ code and have made some modification to try to solve the issue, but that didn't help. The crash stack don't have enough information to help to find the cause.

I could only static review the jni and C++ code, which is slow and helpless. The problem still exists after review. I am a Java developer and not so good at C++, so it is possible that I missed the problematic code. The C++ codebase is large because we used some open source project source code.

Following are some stacks:

```
/ CRASH: com.my.app (pid 27393)
// Short Msg: Native crash
// Long Msg: Native crash: Segmentation fault
// Build Label: Lenovo/heart/heart:10/QKQ1.191014.001/11.5.250_200614:userdebug/test-keys
// Build Changelist: 11.5.250_200614
// Build Time: 1592147934000
// *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
// Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/heart/heart:10/QKQ1.191014.001/11.5.250_200614:userdebug/test-keys'
// Revision: '0'
// ABI: 'arm'
// Timestamp: 2020-10-15 22:44:46+0800
// pid: 27393, tid: 27407, name: ReferenceQueueD  >>> com.my.app <<<
// uid: 10291
// signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4
// Cause: null pointer dereference
//     r0  b7e49de0  r1  00000000  r2  f087cd15  r3  00000000
//     r4  f087cd15  r5  139b8330  r6  139b8330  r7  139b82c8
//     r8  00000000  r9  eb15f600  r10 70ea2bd8  r11 139b8308
//     ip  e5b72bd5  sp  c7e43dc0  lr  71c713bb  pc  f087cd1c
// 
// backtrace:
//       #00 pc 000add1c  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::CanvasJNI::delete_canvas(android::Canvas*)+8) (BuildId: 474c53cb68297e45cf00595c65e14fff)
//       #01 pc 0004a3b9  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (art_jni_trampoline+120) (BuildId: 533d0af7f4307f5a947d9059c8a7d3c40eb37d1b)
//       #02 pc 000bb60f  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry$CleanerThunk.run+78) (BuildId: 533d0af7f4307f5a947d9059c8a7d3c40eb37d1b)
//       #03 pc 0024574b  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (sun.misc.Cleaner.clean+90) (BuildId: 625e004ba4396bf9751878502697218d94469522)
//       #04 pc 000d3849  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueueLocked+168) (BuildId: 625e004ba4396bf9751878502697218d94469522)
//       #05 pc 000d3925  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueuePending+148) (BuildId: 625e004ba4396bf9751878502697218d94469522)
//       #06 pc 000ef941  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal+232) (BuildId: 533d0af7f4307f5a947d9059c8a7d3c40eb37d1b)
//       #07 pc 0009e263  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+146) (BuildId: 533d0af7f4307f5a947d9059c8a7d3c40eb37d1b)
//       #08 pc 00173691  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+64) (BuildId: 625e004ba4396bf9751878502697218d94469522)
//       #09 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #10 pc 0043d13d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+248) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #11 pc 000dff81  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+168) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #12 pc 0037d507  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #13 pc 0037e29b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+302) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #14 pc 003afeff  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1018) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #15 pc 000ab3bd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+20) (BuildId: b8ea1bc56f976308b1ee7e2335b3127e)
//       #16 pc 00061989  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) (BuildId: b8ea1bc56f976308b1ee7e2335b3127e)
```

```
// CRASH: com.my.app (pid 10788)
// Short Msg: Native crash
// Long Msg: Native crash: Segmentation fault
// Build Label: Lenovo/heart/heart:10/QKQ1.191014.001/11.5.250_200614:userdebug/test-keys
// Build Changelist: 11.5.250_200614
// Build Time: 1592147934000
// *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
// Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/heart/heart:10/QKQ1.191014.001/11.5.250_200614:userdebug/test-keys'
// Revision: '0'
// ABI: 'arm'
// Timestamp: 2020-10-16 01:51:56+0800
// pid: 10788, tid: 11437, name: RenderThread  >>> com.my.app <<<
// uid: 10291
// signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x38
// Cause: null pointer dereference
//     r0  c5ddb380  r1  00000000  r2  c607d148  r3  00000000
//     r4  bebe9710  r5  c607d148  r6  00000000  r7  bebe9000
//     r8  ef9a30c0  r9  ef9a30e4  r10 ef9a30e8  r11 f050c018
//     ip  ef9a3a28  sp  c607d070  lr  ef98611b  pc  ef95e6b8
// 
// backtrace:
//       #00 pc 0005a6b8  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::HpGraphicBufferProducer::query(int, int*)+4) (BuildId: 4aade65846c0a0844ffc6abd2cfae7f4)
//       #01 pc 00082119  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::Surface::query(int, int*) const+132) (BuildId: 4aade65846c0a0844ffc6abd2cfae7f4)
//       #02 pc 001f9073  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::getNextFrameSize() const+20) (BuildId: 27f32025e8036c1421e970591d6452bf)
//       #03 pc 001f9045  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::TreeInfo::TreeInfo(android::uirenderer::TreeInfo::TraversalMode, android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext&)+104) (BuildId: 27f32025e8036c1421e970591d6452bf)
//       #04 pc 001f8da7  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::DrawFrameTask::run()+74) (BuildId: 27f32025e8036c1421e970591d6452bf)
//       #05 pc 0020742d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+164) (BuildId: 27f32025e8036c1421e970591d6452bf)
//       #06 pc 0020727f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+54) (BuildId: 27f32025e8036c1421e970591d6452bf)
//       #07 pc 0000d96f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+210) (BuildId: 303a9d221465f0db9b5d760e0a0c6abe)
//       #08 pc 000ab3bd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+20) (BuildId: b8ea1bc56f976308b1ee7e2335b3127e)
//       #09 pc 00061989  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) (BuildId: b8ea1bc56f976308b1ee7e2335b3127e)
```

```
// CRASH: com.my.app (pid 7417)
// Short Msg: Native crash
// Long Msg: Native crash: Segmentation fault
// Build Label: Lenovo/heart/heart:10/QKQ1.191014.001/11.5.250_200614:userdebug/test-keys
// Build Changelist: 11.5.250_200614
// Build Time: 1592147934000
// *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
// Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/heart/heart:10/QKQ1.191014.001/11.5.250_200614:userdebug/test-keys'
// Revision: '0'
// ABI: 'arm'
// Timestamp: 2020-10-16 07:57:24+0800
// pid: 7417, tid: 28261, name: speakLocal tts  >>> com.my.app <<<
// uid: 10291
// signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xfffffff4
//     r0  df8becc0  r1  00000000  r2  00000000  r3  00000001
//     r4  df81ad20  r5  b356b6e0  r6  ef17a9b1  r7  000000a8
//     r8  00000000  r9  ef1a4ad4  r10 ef1a4d08  r11 0065c5c0
//     ip  ef1a4ec4  sp  b356b690  lr  ef1933fd  pc  ef1935b4
// 
// backtrace:
//       #00 pc 000445b4  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::IMediaDeathNotifier::getMediaPlayerService()+476) (BuildId: 4c77835059177de2000d6c39f9539962)
//       #01 pc 0002b9cf  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::MediaPlayer::setDataSource(int, long long, long long)+30) (BuildId: 4c77835059177de2000d6c39f9539962)
//       #02 pc 0003b873  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so (android_media_MediaPlayer_setDataSourceFD(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, long long, long long)+118) (BuildId: c190a7c755ffba7708c716e1dd16c0a1)
//       #03 pc 0029c637  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+126) (BuildId: 39c685939f0d8867d4162c7a38d63ad3600807fd)
//       #04 pc 006ce41b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource+58) (BuildId: 39c685939f0d8867d4162c7a38d63ad3600807fd)
//       #05 pc 006ce365  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource+172) (BuildId: 39c685939f0d8867d4162c7a38d63ad3600807fd)
//       #06 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #07 pc 0043d13d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+248) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #08 pc 000dff81  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+168) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #09 pc 00214673  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+270) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #10 pc 00210867  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+738) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #11 pc 00437927  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+458) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #12 pc 000d6594  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #13 pc 00455d68  /data/app/com.lenovo.menu_assistant-XzP2MzG5jMAB7n94-EP3IQ==/oat/arm/base.vdex (sy.B+1356)
//       #14 pc 00437b91  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1076) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #15 pc 000d6594  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #16 pc 004555cc  /data/app/com.lenovo.menu_assistant-XzP2MzG5jMAB7n94-EP3IQ==/oat/arm/base.vdex (sy.e)
//       #17 pc 00434c9f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+934) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #18 pc 000d2994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #19 pc 00453e6c  /data/app/com.lenovo.menu_assistant-XzP2MzG5jMAB7n94-EP3IQ==/oat/arm/base.vdex (sy$g.run+12)
//       #20 pc 001f068f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.8590219860024250152+166) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #21 pc 001f50a3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+122) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #22 pc 00426b97  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+866) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #23 pc 000dc5a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #24 pc 00173691  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+64) (BuildId: 625e004ba4396bf9751878502697218d94469522)
//       #25 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #26 pc 0043d13d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+248) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #27 pc 000dff81  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+168) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #28 pc 0037d507  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #29 pc 0037e29b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+302) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #30 pc 003afeff  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1018) (BuildId: 78cb259cd8aba2a9f6063413910ab653)
//       #31 pc 000ab3bd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+20) (BuildId: b8ea1bc56f976308b1ee7e2335b3127e)
//       #32 pc 00061989  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) (BuildId: b8ea1bc56f976308b1ee7e2335b3127e)
```

Comment: Without code, we can't help you that much. But try adding assert statements before every call to `android::IMediaDeathNotifier::getMediaPlayerService`,`android::HpGraphicBufferProducer::query` and `android::CanvasJNI::delete_canvas`, so your program will give you a nice error message, in case you pass invalid arguments (Like `NULL` to one of the functions)

Comment: Thanks @JCWasmx86 . But those methods you mentioned are in android system libraries, which I cannot get access to. It is hard for me to give any code. I think the most import thing for me now is to find where the problematic code is.